# Google Drive API + C# ASP.net MVC

Tags: google-api

can anyone share a working example of C# ASP.Net MVC application (accessed from a server - not localhost) which accesses files located on domain's Google Drive?

I am confused between which type of client id is to be used for this kind of access and the different flows used for it.

I am able to access the files using the native client id, but it does not work on the server, get stuck at the following line -

```
 UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = gdocsHelper.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = gdocsHelper.ClientSecret,
            },
            new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

Please guide me through this..